# SVN Client hook script windows

Tags: windows, svn, hook, pre-commit-hook

I have bat script on windows, This script will check for an empty log message,
This code hook script (bat windows):

```
@echo off
::
:: Stops commits that have empty log messages.
::

setlocal

rem Subversion sends through the path to the repository and transaction id
set REPOS=%1
set TXN=%2

rem check for an empty log message
svnlook log %REPOS% -t %TXN% | findstr . > nul
if %errorlevel% gtr 0 (goto err) else exit 0

:err
echo. 1>&2
echo ----ERROR_EN----
echo Your commit has been blocked because you didn't give any log message 1>&2
echo Please write a log message describing the purpose of your changes and 1>&2
echo then try committing again. -- Thank you! 1>&2
echo ----END ERROR_EN----
exit 1
```

I setup hook script như hình [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzkGK.png)

I want to know, Why it alert both empty log messages and have log message.
Image error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cL6y.png)

Thank & br!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine when I tried.
Try echoing %errorlevel% in o/p ie

echo %errorlevel% 1>&2

Also, check if this hook can be implemneted where "repo" is located.
ie inside \hooks\pre-commit.bat

Another possibility is that svnlook command is failed. Check if svnlook command with absolute path. Something like "E:\SVN\bin\svnlook.exe"

Comment: Thankyou very much

Comment: @VinhHoang, I'm not forcing you but generally the correct answer to a question is typically upvoted by the question asker as well.